# Update no of values starting with index in an byte array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a byte array of, let's say, of 100 bytes.

from 0 to 15, these bytes correspond to parameter1,
from 16 to 50, corresponds to parameter2,
from 51 to 80 corresponds to parameter3,
from 81 to 99 corresponds to parameter4

Indexes 1,15,16,50,51,80,81,99 are not fixed. They vary with the parameter

I read the bytes from a device. I have to update, for example, bytes for parameter 3.

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you

P.S. Below is a simple example. I replaced the bytes "23" and "34" with "99"

```
Dim temp As Byte() = New Byte() {12, 23, 12, 23, 34, 56, 67, 89}
Dim tempReplaced As Byte() = New Byte() {12, 23, 12, 99, 99, 56, 67, 89}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Array.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_) will copy a specified set of elements from one array to another.

The following statement will do what you want.

```
Array.Copy(dataArray, parm3Index, parm3Array, 0, parm3Array.Length)
```

Where

- `dataArray` is the data you read from the device
- `parm3Index` is the index of parameter3 in the array
- `parm3Array` is an array containing the bytes that you want to change parameter3 to

Comment: Thank you... It's simpler than my solution. I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Until now I have found this:

```
    Public Shared Sub ReplaceByteArray(ByRef sourceArray As Byte(), arrayToReplace As Byte(), startPosition As Integer, length As Integer)

    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    While counter < length
        sourceArray(startPosition + counter) = arrayToReplace(counter)
        counter += 1
    End While

End Sub
```

Silly me, I thought it was more complicated

If you find another solution more efficient or better, feel free to post it...